# Connect FTP server with Informatica

Tags: informatica

I am relatively new to Informatica and wish to know how to establish connection 
with FTP server.
I have Hostname, username and password information's for the server and am using Informatica's 9.6.1 version with hotfix-4.

Answer (score 0):

In Workflow manager - Connections create an FTP connection.